# Displaying registered routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In this screencast: https://tutsplus.com/lesson/displaying-registered-routes/ Jeffrey Way demonstrates a command he created, and links to the github in the description. However there is an update to say that it is now baked into the Laravel 4 core, however I have searched for it to no avail.

The general idea is that is lists all routes and the action bind to them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're probably still using an older version of the L4 beta. If you download a fresh copy, you'll see it listed when you run `php artisan`.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I enjoyed learning from your screen casts too! Do you plan on doing any more, maybe setting up a simple blog with testing as a focus or something?

Comment: He owns laracasts.com, amazing content.

Comment: JeffreyWay himself answered this? OMG.

Answer (score 62):

Console command:

```
php artisan routes (laravel 4)
php artisan route:list (laravel 5)


+--------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                                | Name                  | Action                                       | Before Filters                                                     | After Filters |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|        | GET /admin/configuration                           |                       | ConfigurationController@index                | auth, keyMaster:configuration                                      |               |
|        | POST /admin/configuration                          |                       | ConfigurationController@update               | auth, keyMaster:configuration                                      |               |
|        | GET /admin/logs/errors                             |                       | LogsController@errors                        | auth, keyMaster:logs/errors                                        |               |
|        | GET /admin/logs/errors/{name}                      |                       | LogsController@errors                        | auth, keyMaster:logs/errors                                        |               |
|        | DELETE /admin/logs/errors                          |                       | LogsController@delete                        | auth, keyMaster:logs/errors                                        |               |
|        | GET /admin/logs/events                             |                       | LogsController@events                        | auth, keyMaster:logs/events                                        |               |
|        | GET /admin/logs/events/data                        |                       | LogsController@eventsData                    | auth, keyMaster:logs/events                                        |               |
```

etc...

Answer (score 24):

I created a route that will list each route and its respective details in an html table.

```
Route::get('routes', function() {
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

    echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>HTTP Method</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Route</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='80%'><h4>Corresponding Action</h4></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->getMethods()[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->getPath() . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->getActionName() . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
});
```

Comment: I have a page that lets me just run some code in laravel, so this was perfect.

Comment: On Laravel 5.6 `getPath()` method was changed to `uri()`

Comment: In laravel 7, use `methods` instead of `getMethods`. You can also get the name inside the foreach loop using the `$value->getName()` method.

Answer (score 9):

You can use my library: [asvae/laravel-api-tester](https://github.com/asvae/laravel-api-tester):

- [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/q1AAPlh.gifv)
- [demo](http://laravel-api-tester.asva.by/api-tester)

[image: Laravel api tester]

---

To show all routes in console in **Laravel 5+** do:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: You mean `php artisan route:list`, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

For Lavarel 5 and 5+ command is :

```
php artisan route:list
```

For Lower version Lavarel ( Lower than Lavarel 5), it would be :

```
php artisan routes
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know this might be helpful or not but I'll just share it here.

You can use this command in terminal to find total number of registered route in Laravel.

```
php artisan route:list | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below function for `Laravel 5.8`

```
$routes = collect(\Route::getRoutes())
                    ->map(function ($route) { 
                            return  array(
                                            'domain' => $route->domain(),
                                            'method' => implode('|', $route->methods()),
                                            'uri'    => $route->uri(),
                                            'name'   => $route->getName(),
                                            'action' => ltrim($route->getActionName(), '\\'),
                                            'middleware' => collect($route->gatherMiddleware())
                                                            ->map(function ($middleware) {
                                                                return $middleware instanceof Closure ? 'Closure' : $middleware;
                                                            })->implode(','),
                                        ); 
                        });
```

Please check below link for reference:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php

OR

You can use the following code:

```
foreach (\Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes() as $route)
        {
            $action = $route->getAction();
            $uri = $route->uri();

            if (array_key_exists('controller', $action))
            {               
                // You can also use explode('@', $action['controller']); here
                // to separate the class name from the method

                if(isset($action['as']) && !empty($action['as'])){

                    $controller = explode("@",str_replace($action['namespace']."\\","",$action['controller']));

                    $controllers[$controller[0]][$action['as']] = array('router_group' => $action['middleware'], 'function' => $controller[1], 'uri' => $uri);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

ON laravel 5.6 or newer, based on jeanfrg's answer, use this:

```
Route::get('routes', function() {
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes(); 

    echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>HTTP Method</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Route</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='80%'><h4>Corresponding Action</h4></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->methods()[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->uri() . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->getActionName() . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Update for laravel 5.4

```
Route::get('routes', function() {
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
    echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>HTTP Method</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Route</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='80%'><h4>Corresponding Action</h4></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->methods()[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->uri() . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->getActionName() . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
});
```

Comment: This is the exact same code that Homer posted 3 months ago. It should not be a new answer. If it is to say that it works already in 5.4, then it would need to be a comment, not an answer.