# How to get a list of registered route paths in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I was hoping to find a way to create an array with the registered routes paths within Laravel 4.

Essentially, I am looking to get a list something like this returned:

```
/
/login
/join
/password
```

I did come across a method `Route::getRoutes()` which returns an object with the routes information as well as the resources but the path information is protected and I don't have direct access to the information.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Perhaps a different method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying registered routes in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955295/displaying-registered-routes-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

`Route::getRoutes()` returns a `RouteCollection`. On each element, you can do a simple `$route->getPath()` to get path of the current route.

Each protected parameter can be get with a standard getter.

Looping works like this:

```
$routeCollection = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getRoutes();

foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    echo $value->getPath();
}
```

Comment: how did you iterate through collection?

Comment: Can I use this in a custom helper?

Comment: @RajanRawal `Collection`s implement `ArrayAccess` which allows them to behave just like arrays, and be used in the `foreach`.

Comment: if you prefer to avoid Facades, you can inject `Illuminate\Routing\Router`.

Comment: Laravel 5.2.*
`$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes(); dd($routeCollection);`

Comment: Just in case someone finds it useful, with Laravel >= 5.5 you can use: 

    `$routes = array_map(function (\Illuminate\Routing\Route $route)
    {
        return $route->uri;
    }, (array) Route::getRoutes()->getIterator());`

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route

Comment: $route->uri() is the function :D ( if you prefer it, over accessing the public property uri )

Answer (score 105):

You can use console command:

> **Laravel 4** *as asked in question*

```
php artisan routes
```

> **Laravel 5** *more actual*

```
php artisan route:list
```

Helpers *(Laravel 4)* :

```
Usage:
 routes [--name[="..."]] [--path[="..."]]

Options:
 --name                Filter the routes by name.
 --path                Filter the routes by path.
 --help (-h)           Display this help message.
 --quiet (-q)          Do not output any message.
 --verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for     more verbose output and 3 for debug
 --version (-V)        Display this application version.
 --ansi                Force ANSI output.
 --no-ansi             Disable ANSI output.
 --no-interaction (-n) Do not ask any interactive question.
 --env                 The environment the command should run under.
```

Comment: This is `php artisan route:list` now

Comment: That is true for Laravel 5, but the question was for Laravel 4

Comment: `php artisan route:list` returns “There are no commands defined in the "route" namespace.” in Laravel 8. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 36):

Improving @jeanfrg's answer

It has a few deprecated functions. It shows error while editing an answer, hence posting it here.

**Laravel 6, 7 & 8**

Put it inside `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('routes', function () {
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

    echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='10%'><h4>HTTP Method</h4></td>";
    echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Route</h4></td>";
    echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Name</h4></td>";
    echo "<td width='70%'><h4>Corresponding Action</h4></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $value->methods()[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value->uri() . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value->getName() . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value->getActionName() . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
});
```

**Demo:**
Access it via `<url>/routes`

[image: Output demo]

Answer (score 32):

For Laravel 5, you can use artisan command

`php artisan route:list` instead of `php artisan routes`.

Comment: This is not true of 5.4

Answer (score 28):

I created a route that will list each route and its respective details in an html table.

```
Route::get('routes', function() {
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

    echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td width='10%'><h4>HTTP Method</h4></td>";
            echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Route</h4></td>";
            echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Name</h4></td>";
            echo "<td width='70%'><h4>Corresponding Action</h4></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $value->getMethods()[0] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $value->getPath() . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $value->getName() . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $value->getActionName() . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
});
```

Answer (score 14):

```
//Laravel >= 5.4

//Controller index()
$app = app();
$routes = $app->routes->getRoutes();
return view ('Admin::routes.index',compact('routes'));

//view
<table id="routes-table" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
       <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>uri</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Method</th>
                </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
                @foreach ($routes as $route )
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$route->uri}}</td>
                        <td>{{$route->getName()}}</td>
                        <td>{{$route->getPrefix()}}</td>
                        <td>{{$route->getActionMethod()}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer and add a short explanation about what it does and how it works? Thank you!

Comment: @FabioTurati We are just getting all the routes from Laravel `getRoutes()` method, then sending them to the `template`, then finally create a normal `html table` with the data while looping through all of them. For instance we are displaying the `uri e.g /home`, `name e.g home_route` you assigned and the others.

Comment: Works for Laravel 5.6.x Thanks

Answer (score 7):

A better way to get it readable is to register a route and print it in web browser with the artisan output directly

```
Route::get('routes', function() {
     \Artisan::call('route:list');
     return \Artisan::output();
});
```

Comment: Better change the last line of the Closure to `return '<pre>' . \Artisan::output() . '</pre>';` for better formatting.

Comment: Ány Idea how to filter this? For example for routes which start like this `api/`

Comment: @utdev I know this is old comments, you can pass the parameter to filter like this `\Artisan::call('route:list', ['--path' => 'api']);`

Answer (score 5):

if you have compiled routes like /login/{id} and you want prefix only:

```
foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
    $compiled = $route->getCompiled();
    if(!is_null($compiled))
    {
        var_dump($compiled->getStaticPrefix());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Code

#### Laravel <= 5.3

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route $routes  */
$routes = Route::getRoutes();
foreach ($routes as $route) {
    /** @var \Illuminate\Routing\Route $route  */
    echo $route->getPath() .  PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Laravel >= 5.4

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route $routes  */
$routes = Route::getRoutes();
foreach ($routes as $route) {
    /** @var \Illuminate\Routing\Route $route  */
    echo $route->uri. PHP_EOL;
}
```

### Artisan

#### Laravel 4

```
php artisan routes
```

#### Laravel 5

```
php artisan route:list
```

Answer (score 3):

```php
$routeList = Route::getRoutes();

foreach ($routeList as $value)
{
    echo $value->uri().'<br>';
}

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

On Laravel 5.4, it works, 100 %

Answer (score 1):

Console command for those who use [Oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) with [Laravel 5 plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/laravel5/laravel5.plugin.zsh)

```
la5routes
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all the routes are available all the time.

For example if you want to get the routes from the `RouteServiceProvider` then you might need to use the `booted` callback:

```
    $this->booted(function () {
        dump(Route::getRoutes());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Laravel 5.4.* This code works fine.**

```
Route::get('routes', function() {
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>HTTP Method</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Route</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='10%'><h4>Name</h4></td>";
        echo "<td width='70%'><h4>Corresponding Action</h4></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->methods()[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->uri() . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->getName() . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $value->getActionName() . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
});
```