# Laravel 5: how to get the paths of all routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to get a list of the paths of all routes programmatically.

I tried `Route::getRoutes()` - not working in L5. `RouteCollection::getRoutes()` - is not a static method.

I bet I can get the `RouteCollection` from `$request`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Route::getRoutes();` should work, you might have forgotten to import the route class (facade). Then you iterate the list:

```
$routeList = Route::getRoutes();

foreach ($routeList as $value)
{
    echo $value->getPath();
}
```

Remember to import

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

This is tested on Laravel 5.2

[Documenation](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html)

Comment: This works! Thank you. I didn't include the "use" statement, so another Route class seems to been used.

Comment: hey it does not work in laravel 5.4, what code shoul i use.

Comment: @nikeshadhikari look at the dock for 5.4 it is still there https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html

Comment: getPath() not working in laravel 5.4 . how can i solve this?

Answer (score 3):

First

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

For all routes use this code

```
$routeList=Route::getRoutes();
    foreach ($routeList as $value) {
        echo $value->getPath();
    }
```

For the current route name use this code

```
$currentPath= Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();
```

For details information, read these two posts,
[All Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394891/how-to-get-a-list-of-registered-route-paths-in-laravel)

and [Current Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046691/how-to-get-current-route-name-in-laravel-5)