# Get routes of a specific path via Route::getRoutes() laravel method

Tags: php, laravel

Question is Obvious.

we know that with `Route::getRoutes()` method can get all defined routes in laravel project like this :

```
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
$arr    =   [];

foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    $arr[] =    $value->getPath();
}

return array_unique($arr);
```

But I want to get all defined routes in specific path for example `/admin`.

I thought that can pass a path name to `getRoutes()` for do that but does not work for me.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that makes use of Laravel's collections:

```
$routes = collect(Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes())->reduce(function ($carry = [], $route) {
    !starts_with($route->getPath(), 'admin') ?: $carry[] = $route->getPath();

    return  $carry;
});
```

So now the `routes` array will return a list of the route paths that start with `admin`. Here's what's going on there:

- Using `Route::getRoutes()` will return a [`RoutesCollection`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html) which has its own `getRoutes` method that returns a flat array of [`Illuminate\Routing\Route`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html) instances. You can then pass that to the `collect` method which will return a `Collection` of all those routes.
- Now you just have to remove the values that do not start with `admin`. If that was a simple array of values that could be easily achieved with the [`filter`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-filter) method, but since this is an array of objects and you want the `path` string that is accessible only via a method call to `getPath`, the collection's [`reduce`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-reduce) method can be used instead as a workaround.

Also, you'll notice that the condition checks if the path starts with `admin` and not `/admin`. That's because the Laravel router will strip leading slashes automatically when building the route collection.

---

You can read more about collections in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections).

Comment: I upgraded laravel to 5.5 and now got error : `Method getPath does not exist.`. seems that it is removed. is there any replacement to that ?

Comment: The replacement is `uri()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this apporach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394891/how-to-get-a-list-of-registered-route-paths-in-laravel):

```
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
$adminRoutes = [];

foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    strpos($value->getPath(), 'admin') === false ?: $adminRoutes[] = $value->getPath();
}
```

Comment: The `getRoutes()` method returns a `RoutesCollection` instance, and unlike a regular `Collection` it does not have any `where` method, so this won't work. Please revise your answer.

Comment: Now I will know that, thanks. I guess in this case best approach will be just to use simple loop to filter routes. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for regex:

```
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
    $arr             = [];

    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        if (preg_match('/^\/?admin/', $value->getPath())) {
            $arr[] = $value->getPath();
        }
    }
    $filteredRoutes = array_unique($arr);
```