# How to get a list of web routes in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I've tried the following but the return is null.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {

        $routeList = Route::getRoutes();

        foreach ($routeList as $value) {
            dd($value->getPath());
        }

    }

}
```

My route file:

```
<?php    
Route::namespace('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('admin/post', 'PostController@index')->name('posts');
    Route::get('admin/post/new', 'PostController@new')->name('post_new');
    Route::post('admin/post/save', 'SubjectController@save')->name('post_save');
});
```

I tried several ways, but I can not list the routes created in the web.php routes file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394891/how-to-get-a-list-of-registered-route-paths-in-laravel

Comment: try in a controller function

Comment: @Sohel0415 As written in the comments this does not work with Laravel 5.5

Comment: ow! miss that part

Comment: You may want to look into the Pretty Routes package - even if you don't wish to use it, perhaps you can find a good solution in its source code. :) Link: https://github.com/garygreen/pretty-routes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will provide every details about `routes`.

```
$routes = app('router')->getRoutes();

return  $arrays=(array) $routes;
```

Comment: `getRoutes()` method gives out the `RouteCollection` object, which contains 4 variables with duplicated data in them. In order to specifically get All routes, I did: `app('router')->getRoutes()->get();`

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use them in your controller to use the programmatically, then you can access them through the Route Class via Route::getRoutes().

```
    use \Route;
    dd(Route::getRoutes());
```

To review/analyze the list of routes however, I just use the [artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan) command line in the root of your application:

```
php artisan route:list
```

If you have a bash, you can even look for specific routes with grep.

```
php artisan route:list |grep users
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `php artisan route:list |grep users` is useful. thanks