# Laravel get routes by method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

How can I get all routes in project which have `GET` method? I have tried:

`Route::getRoutes()` which gave me all routes but somehow I could not have filtered them by method.

The `Route::getRoutes()->routes` would be nice to have but routes is protected property and I do not see any `getter`.

Comment: what does `Route::getRoutes()` give you? could you not filter that result into only get? Apparently it gives you back an array so you could run it through `array_filter` to get only the ones you want

Comment: I get a collection:

`
RouteCollection {#28 ▼
  #routes: array:7 [▼
    "GET" => array:124 [▶]
    "HEAD" => array:124 [▶]
    "POST" => array:63 [▶]
    "PUT" => array:1 [▶]
    "PATCH" => array:1 [▶]
    "DELETE" => array:21 [▶]
    "OPTIONS" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
...
from which I would like to get only GET routes

Comment: in that case maybe `Route::getRoutes()['GET']` it's a little hard to read in your comment

Comment: There is also getRouteByMethod() see this api page https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html#method_getRoutes

Comment: Couldn't you do the same as what's done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18395300/5283119). Get all routes, loop over them and create your own array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create small helper method.

```
function getRoutesByMethod(string $method){
    $routes = \Route::getRoutes()->getRoutesByMethod();
    return $routes[$method];
}
```

then use it in your application

```
$postRoutes = getRoutesByMethod("POST");
```

Answer (score 2):

The RouteCollection has a method to sort the routes by their method(eg. GET).

You can use it as below to get the GET routes:

```
Route::getRoutes()->getRoutesByMethod()['GET']
```

And to get POST routes:

```
Route::getRoutes()->getRoutesByMethod()['POST']
```