# Generate overview of a complex Laravel project

Tags: laravel

I had to do some changes on a complex Laravel project which I was not familiar. It took quite some time to navigate and find correct files. Is there any package/tool for generating overview of a Laravel project. I would prefer to generate something like this.

```
route             ->   controller@function             ->   models       ->    view
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
reports/orders/   ->  ReportsController@print_orders   -> Report, Order  -> reports/index
...
```

I am aware of `php artisan route:list` but it doesn't show all the details.

Comment: A good IDE like PHPStorm or VSCode, with the proper PHP plugins, does most of this for you. I can click a route definition to get to the controller function, I can click a view() call to get to its Blade file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this: `php artisan r:l -v` and `php artisan r:l -h`

Comment: you need to add some explaination about your answer. so please add meaning of `-v` & `-h`  option flag in your answer. what is use of that flag

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about models and views but you can do it by creating custom console command for that or you can create a view for it:

```
Artisan::command('route:list', function () {
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
    $this->comment("Methods, URI|");
    $this->comment("-----------------------------------");
    foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
        $this->comment($value->methods()[0].", ".$value->uri());
    }
})
```

Possible methods which can be use are in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html#method_getRoutes)

[You can get help from here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394891/how-to-get-a-list-of-registered-route-paths-in-laravel)